# Delphi 2010: Group TListView items in vsReport ViewStyle

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tlistview

Firstly is this possible?

I have two issues - the fist is that I cannot get the groups to appear in the TListView when creating at run time.  I'm using the following code:

```
lg := lvResults.Groups.Add;
lg.Header := 'New Starters';
lg.GroupID := 0;
```

The second is that even if I create groups at design time - I can see them in the form designer - they are absent in at run time - even before I refresh the data to add my own Items...

Additional:
I have confirmed the answer below works on a virgin project.  However it fails in the Project where I want to use it!  I have replaced my TListView with a new one from the palette and no joy.  The list view is on a tpagecontrol

Comment: Solution was that the Project had "Enable Runtime themes" disabled - without which Groups apparantly don't work

Comment: that makes sense. It would have been daft to have backported them to Windows Classic.

Comment: @DanKelly What adverse affect does enabling "Enable Runtime themes" have, if any?

Comment: In my case `OwnerData` was enabled:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231179/does-groupview-work-in-the-tlistview-in-ownerdata-mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code below results in visible groups. Are you perhaps forgetting to set `GroupView` to `True`?

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Group: TListGroup;
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  ListView1.GroupView := True;
  ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'My column';
  Group := ListView1.Groups.Add;
  Group.Header := 'My header';
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.GroupID := Group.GroupID;
  Item.Caption := 'My item';
```

[image]

There is an code example in the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/ListGroups_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: Out of interest: did you try with vsReport as well? That's what is in the title of the question (would have been smarter to repeat it in the question as well)...

Comment: @Marjan Didn't spot that bit thanks. Answer updated to cover that angle now.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work for me.  I've removed all the columns, items, etc from the designed listview, replaced the code with the above, commenting all mine out, and all I get is  "My Column" and "My Item"

Comment: OK, just tested on a fresh project and it works... time to spot the difference... thanks

Comment: GroupID is assigned automatically (starting at 0), so `Group.GroupID := 0;` is not required, and use `Item.GroupID := Group.GroupID;` instead

Comment: @Alister it's nice to be explicit and it gives the reader the cue for what is needed to introduce a second group

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `GroupID` will automatically be 1 for the second (and 2 for the third etc), manually assigning `GroupID` is possibly not a good idea, but I see your point.  If we are going to be really pedantic `s1` and `s2` are never used. Also runtime themes need to be enabled for groups to be visible (which is what caught me up)