# Does GroupView work in the TListView in OwnerData mode?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-xe2, tlistview

I'm trying to implement an "Arrange by" feature for a TListView in Delphi XE2.  In the form designer (if I turn off OwnerData) I can get groups to show up and add items to them

However, if I try setting

```
 procedure TMyForm.LVData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
  Item.GroupID := 0;
```

None of my list items are placed in the group.

---

*Perfunctory information you may also want to know*

1. ListView is in report mode
2. Themes are enabled for application (running on Windows 7)
3. GroupView is enabled
4. Yes, I have a group with an ID of 0

Answer (score 3):

Upon further googling, the [answer is no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> The following messages are not supported under the LVS_OWNERDATA style: **LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW**, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, LVM_SETTILEINFO, and LVM_MAPIDTOINDEX.

That would be some helpful info in the Embarcadero Help file and Delphi IDE.

(maybe uncheck groupview when owner data is checked, eh?)